# XML Parse with SAX

Tags: java, android, xml, sax

hi im having trouble figuring out that to do to get my XML file to read.

Im using Sax but i cant seem to get the child nodes of the "ansArray" to be read by SAX. Im not sure if my XML is wrongly formatted any help would be great.

NB
The XML Doc was saved by Using XStream which is why "AnsArray" has 4 string items.

XML DOC:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
  <questionList>
    <Question>
      <id>-1</id>
      <question>&quot;Who Was Sleepless In Seattle With Meg Ryan?&quot;</question>
      <ansArray>
        <string>&quot;Bruce Willis&quot;</string>
        <string>&quot;Arnie Schwarzenegger&quot;</string>
        <string>&quot;Joe Pesci&quot;</string>
        <string>&quot;Tom Hanks&quot;</string>
      </ansArray>
      <correctAns>4</correctAns>
      <iDifficulty>2</iDifficulty>
    </Question>
    <Question>
      <id>-1</id>
      <question>&quot;who was the Terminator?&quot;</question>
      <ansArray>
        <string>&quot;John Travolta&quot;</string>
        <string>&quot;Stevan Segal&quot;</string>
        <string>&quot;Arnie Schwarzenegger&quot;</string>
        <string>&quot;Al Pacino&quot;</string>
      </ansArray>
      <correctAns>3</correctAns>
      <iDifficulty>3</iDifficulty>
    </Question>
 </questionList>
```

In the above XML file i can read everything except the child noes of ansArray i.e

```
  <ansArray>
    <string>&quot;John Travolta&quot;</string>
    <string>&quot;Stevan Segal&quot;</string>
    <string>&quot;Arnie Schwarzenegger&quot;</string>
    <string>&quot;Al Pacino&quot;</string>
  </ansArray>
```

SAX XML Code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

public class SAX_XMLReader extends DefaultHandler {

    boolean currentElement = false;
    String currentValue = "";

    static Question question;
    static ArrayList<Question> questionList=new ArrayList<Question>();

    ArrayList<String> sAnswers=new ArrayList<String>(4);   

    public static ArrayList<Question> getquestionList() {
        return questionList;
    }

    @Override
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
            Attributes atts) throws SAXException {

        currentElement = true;

        //System.out.println("qName = "+qName );

        if (qName.equals("questionList")) {
            questionList = new ArrayList<Question>();
        } else if (qName.equals("Question")) {
            question = new Question();
        } //how to handle the answer string array
        else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("ansArray")) { 
              //??
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
            throws SAXException {

        currentElement = false;

        //System.out.println("qName = "+qName );

        if(qName.equals("question")) 
        {
            question.setQuestion(currentValue.trim());
            //System.out.println("Q: "+currentValue.trim());
        } 
        else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("correctAns")) {
            question.setCorrectAns(Integer.parseInt(currentValue.trim()));            
        } 
        else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("iDifficulty")) {
            question.setiDifficulty(Integer.parseInt(currentValue.trim()));        
        }    
        else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("ansArray")) {
            //??
        }             

        else if (qName.equals("Question")) {
            questionList.add(question);
        }

        currentValue = "";            

    }

    @Override
    public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
            throws SAXException {

        if (currentElement) {
            currentValue = currentValue + new String(ch, start, length);
        }

    }

}
```

Question Class:

```
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.annotations.XStreamAlias;
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream;
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.annotations.XStreamImplicit;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

//change string array to list

public class Question implements Serializable{

    private int id=-1;        
    private String question="";        
    //private String[] ansArray = new String[4];        
        ArrayList<String> sAnswers=new ArrayList<String>(4);     
    private int correctAns=-1;
    private int iDifficulty=-1;


    public Question(){
            //sAnswers=new ArrayList<String>();
            for(int x=0;x<4;x++){
                sAnswers.add("default answer "+x);
            }
    }

    //testing contructor
        public Question(int id,String sQuestion){

                this.id=id;
        this.question =sQuestion;
    }


    public Question(int id,String sQuestion,String sAns1){

                this.id=id;
        this.question =sQuestion;
                this.sAnswers.add(sAns1);

        //this.ansArray[0]=sAns1;
    }

    public Question(String sQuestion,String sAns1,String sAns2,String sAns3,String sAns4,int iCorrectAns){

                this.question =sQuestion;
        this.sAnswers.add(sAns1);
                this.sAnswers.add(sAns2);
                this.sAnswers.add(sAns3);
                this.sAnswers.add(sAns4);
        this.correctAns =iCorrectAns;
    }

    //constuctor with difficuly int(1-15)
    public Question(String sQuestion,String sAns1,String sAns2,String sAns3,String sAns4,int iCorrectAns,int iDifficulty){

                this.question =sQuestion;
        this.sAnswers.add(sAns1);
                this.sAnswers.add(sAns2);
                this.sAnswers.add(sAns3);
                this.sAnswers.add(sAns4);
        this.correctAns =iCorrectAns;
        this.iDifficulty=iDifficulty;
    }

    //constuctor with difficuly int(1-15)
    public Question(int id,String sQuestion,String sAns1,String sAns2,String sAns3,String sAns4,int iCorrectAns,int iDifficulty){

                this.id=id;
        this.question =sQuestion;
        this.sAnswers.add(sAns1);
                this.sAnswers.add(sAns2);
                this.sAnswers.add(sAns3);
                this.sAnswers.add(sAns4);
        this.correctAns =iCorrectAns;
        this.iDifficulty=iDifficulty;
    }



    public int getiDifficulty() {
        return iDifficulty;
    }

    public void setiDifficulty(int iDifficulty) {
        this.iDifficulty = iDifficulty;
    }

    public int getID() {
        return id;
    }


    public void setID(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


    public String getQuestion() {
        return question;
    }


    public void setQuestion(String question) {
        this.question = question;
    }


    public String getAnswer(int i){
            return sAnswers.get(i);

    }


    public void setAnswer(int i,String answer){     
            sAnswers.add(answer);
    }


    //get the correct answer as a string
    public String sGetCorrectAnswer(){
        return sAnswers.get(correctAns);
    }


    public String getAnswersList()
    {
        String s="\nA) " + sAnswers.get(0) + 
                 "\nB) " + sAnswers.get(1) +
                 "\nC) " + sAnswers.get(2) +
                 "\nD) " + sAnswers.get(3);
        return s;
    }


    public int getiCorrectAns() {
        return correctAns;
    }
    public void setCorrectAns(int correctAns) {
        this.correctAns = correctAns;
    }


        @Override
    public String toString(){

        String log ="\n\nQuestion by ID" +
                "\n\nId: "+this.getID()+
                "\nQuestion: " + this.getQuestion() + 
                " \nAns1: " + this.getAnswer(0) +
                " \nAns2: " + this.getAnswer(1) +
                " \nAns3: " + this.getAnswer(2) +
                " \nAns4: " + this.getAnswer(3) +
                " \nCorrectAns: " + this.getiCorrectAns()+
                " \nDifficulty: " + this.getiDifficulty()
                ; 
        return log;
    }



}
```

Comment: Umm.. why not use the XmlPullParser ?

Comment: Sax-parser is a very good way for reading xml-files. It is supported on many platforms and you may parse vety large xml files with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`startElement()` is called each time a xml-start-tag is found. That means it is for the following elements (qname) from you example:

- questionList
- Question
- id
- question
- ansArray
- string
- string
- string
- string
- correctAns
- iDifficulty
- Question
- id
- question
- ansArray
- string
- string
- string
- string
- correctAns
- iDifficulty

That means you have to manage your location in the xml-data yourself (level, element-tree).

Comment: thanks for the help you put on the right track and i got it working at last.